# How to Set Timeout for FastAGI in Asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk, fastagi

I have a server that sends FastAGI requests over TCP to another server in the Internet. The problem is that the default timeout for FastAGI is very short and the error below is raised.

**How can I set FastAGI timeout in my dialplan?**

```
 FastAGI connection to 'agi://Myserver/agi' timed out after MAX_AGI_CONNECT (2000) milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2sec timeout is not "very short". I can't imagine situation when application can't answer in 2 sec. Very likly  you have issue with other side.

However if you are sure you need timeout more then 2sec(if you internet go 3 times worldwide via satelite links), you can change that timeout in asterisk source and recompile asterisk.

To got exactly place you can use something like this:

```
asterisk-1.8.11.1]# grep MAX_AGI_CONNECT * -rn|grep define
res/res_agi.c:918:#define MAX_AGI_CONNECT 2000
```

Comment: I have the same problem but there is no such directory in Asterisk server named 'res/res_agi.c' where I can change the "#define MAX_AGI_CONNECT".
I am using Asterisk 1.8, how can this be resolved. i would appreciate any help in this.

Comment: It is not an asterisk issue. Issue with your fastagi app or firewall.