# Set Timeout for MAX_AGI_CONNECT in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have an Asterisk installed and a Zoiper softphone. Whenever we make a call, there is an error displayed on Asterisk :

> WARNING[28761]: res_agi.c:1498 launch_netscript: FastAGI connection to
>   'agi://0.0.0.0/incoming.agi' timed out after MAX_AGI_CONNECT (2000)
>   milliseconds.
>       -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/123-0000003d' status is 'UNKNOWN'

It takes approx 10 seconds to connect a call, but as the Time-out is for 2 sec, thus the call is never connected.

My question is : How can we change the default Time-out from 2000ms to 15000ms ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that in some point of your dialplan there is AGI that can't be executed. It's look like this:

```
exten => ????,n,AGI(agi://0.0.0.0/incoming.agi)
```

If you need it you have to fix your script to receive connection in proper way or change dialplan.

In case you realy need this, you can [change timeout in sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18546560/1912753)

Comment: Thanks for your time but I would like to know how can I find this AGI, where does this exist ?
Also, what can I do to increase the Time-Out Limit to 15000ms
Where shall the code (in the Link you provided) is to be placed ?

Comment: I am using vTiger 6.1, when I click a number it makes a call to my Zoiper and when I click on ANSWER, the call is then connected to the number I clicked on vTiger. Now the call cannot be connected as it gets Timed Out in 2 sec only. But when I dial the call through Zoiper-Asterisk independently (without vTiger), the call gets connected in 10 secs. Can you suggest me WHERE exactly is the code placed and what do I need to do to increase the Time Out ?

Comment: Usually this configuration can be found in `etc/asterisk/extensions.conf`. There you can specify what will happened when Zoiper (or other sip client) dial specific number.